# Perl "my $bar if 0;" vs "my $bar = undef if 0;"

Tags: perl, variable-declaration, variable-initialization

The following code will return an error,

```
$ perl -E'sub foo { my $bar if 0; $bar++ }'
This use of my() in false conditional is no longer allowed at -e line 1.
```

But this code

```
$ perl -E'sub foo { my $bar = undef if 0; $bar++ }'
```

Does not return an error. Is there any difference between these two forms?

Comment: "Undefined behavior" in the second case, so broken code.  (The first one is outright bizarre -- how could one conditionally _declare_ a variable?)

Comment: @zdim It's conditionally declared in the second as well. People used it as a hack to get a `state`-like effect.

Comment: @ikegami Sure. But in the second case at least _the intent appears to be_ that the assignment is conditioned. (As for an actual "difference", the question itself shows one -- in how the code is processed.  Otherwise, of course, both have the same problem of "mixing" compile-time and run-time effects.)  I didn't know of such use of it though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`my` has a compile-time effect and a run-time effect, and you don't want to use a `my` variable without first having its run-time effect.

Since the problematic situation is using a `my` variable under different conditions than it was declared, there is no difference between your two snippets. Both should be avoided.

To create a persistent variable scoped to a sub, you can use

```perl
{
   my $bar = 0;
   sub foo {
      return $bar++;
   }
}
```

or

```perl
use feature qw( state );  # 5.10+

sub foo {
   state $bar = 0;
   return $bar++;
}
```